# curl: no URL specified - -F: command not found

Tags: php, linux, bash, curl

Hi I am using this code to upload a file on Linux from a bash script:

```
curl -F aok=2 -F Name='azko' -F dir="@path_to_file;filename=zou.odp" 
 -F "tag=1234" -F "OK=2" -F ecoTime=1 -F 
 -F ckx=no "http://blabla"
```

However the error I receive:

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
./up.sh: line 2: -F: command not found
./up.sh: line 3: -F: command not found
```

I have curl 7.47.0 installed.

So far I tried to put \ at the end of the lines but the error still keeps coming. What am I missing?

When I directly copy this code with \ placed to the terminal it works but this time gives another kind of error

```
curl: (43) A libcurl function was given a bad argument
```

I am guessing this is from a directory problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using -F -F without arguments.
Try:

```
curl -F aok=2 -F Name='azko' -F "dir=@path_to_file;filename=zou.odp" -F "tag=1234" -F "OK=2" -F ecoTime=1 -F ckx=no "http://blabla"
```

Also you have either write the whole command in one line (see above) or add `\` to the end of the line if the command continues:

```
curl -F aok=2 -F Name='azko' -F "dir=@path_to_file;filename=zou.odp" \
 -F "tag=1234" -F "OK=2" -F ecoTime=1 \
 -F ckx=no "http://blabla"
```

Comment: Ah.. Thanks the double -F -F.... However, even after I correct the code, It still gives the "curl: (43) A libcurl function was given a bad argument" error.. When I say -F dir="@/commoncomp/Downloads/12;filename=zou.odp" it does not work, but once I switch it to  -F dir="@/commoncomp/Downloads/12/zou.odp" it works. However, I would like to use it with giving a directory because will be much easier for me to upload several files once linked..

Comment: Try setting the " arround the whole statement. I've updated both statements above. WRONG:`dir="@path_to_file;filename=zou.odp"` RIGHT:`"dir=@path_to_file;filename=zou.odp"`

Comment: Thank you :) now everythng is okey